# cd back to previous location in Cmder

Tags: conemu, cmder

In bash you can type:

```
cd -
```

to go back to your previous location.

**How do I do this in Cmder?**

Answer (score 1):

In cmd you can use `pushd` to change folders taking care of the history

```
pushd C:\some\path
```

And use `popd` to return one step before

```
popd
```

Answer (score -1):

In Cmder or any other cmd you can just use

```
cd..
```

Comment: This goes one step up in the directory.

It does not go to your previous location, unless your previous location was the parent directory of your current location.